# Variable encoding in R- Survey - Ranking nominal variables

Tags: r, encoding, statistics, survey

Despite my research I don't understand how to define (and so code) some results of my survey.

I have questions that asked respondant to rank the modalities, ex : Classify the following means of transport based on your preferences : car, train, plane.
And, others that ased to rank on a scale their perception regarding a product, ex : On a scale from one to ten, evaluate something.

I think that in the later case, Likert scale is appropriated (is there other method ?). However I've not idea of what I've to use for the first one.

Any idea please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  The second example is an ordered scale, often called a Lickert scale.  Youyr first exampe is simply an unordered scale.  You can use either a `factor`, a `character` or a numeric to record it.  If you use a numeric, you'd need some way of formatting the output.  It would also be *completely wrong* to draw any conclusions about  differences between subgroups in your data based on numeric differences* of your numeric codes in this place.  You should only look at relative frequencies.

- By this I mean saying things like "The mean mode of transport was 1.2 in subgroup A and 4.3 in subgroup B".  Instead, you should limit yourself to staements such as "In subgroup A, the preferred mode of transport was 'plane`, with 43% of respondents making it their first choice, where as in subgroup B,`bike was the most popular choice, with 67% od respondents ranking it as their first preference".

Comment: Thank you ! If I understand well I've to create variables named for example first choice, second choice, third choice, ... and convert the modalities of these variables to factor. Such that I'll have for example first_choice_car valuation relative to first_choice_plane with plane the reference level of the variable first_choice, otherwise how to take into consideration the ranking please ?